# Can we create boost socket with a socket already open?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a code that create me a socket throught a stunServer for my peer to peer software and I'm wondering if it's possible to create a boost::udp::socket with a socket already open ?

I have already search in the boost documentation but i found nothing that permited this .

Comment: Are you talking about binding to a local address, or connecting to the same host? You can bind a TCP and an UDP socket to the same port, as the protocols are different, but you can't bind two UDP sockets to the same local port.

Comment: I think he means constructing an instance of `boost::udp::socket` using an existing file handle. (And the answer is yes, with the `assign` member function.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
io_service ios;
ip::udp::socket socket(ios);
int native_socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
socket1.assign(ip::udp::v4(), native_socket);
```

See [this sample code](http://svn.netlabs.org/repos/ports/boost/trunk/libs/asio/test/ip/udp.cpp) for more.

Comment: I have an exception : "invalid argument" or "File exist", if my socket is open with socket and just after bind. does it work ? –